# How to retrieve the generated SQL query from create_sql_agent of Langchain?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, langchain, large-language-model

I have used **Langchain** - **create_sql_agent** to generate SQL queries with a database and get the output result of the generated SQL query. Here is how my code looks like, it is working pretty well.

```
agent = create_sql_agent(
    llm=llm,
    db=db,
    verbose=True,
    agent_type= "openai-tools",
)
response = agent.invoke({"input": "How many resources are there in XYZ location?"})
```

Here is how the response looks like:

```
{'input': 'How many resources are there in XYZ location?',
 'output': 'There are total 15 agents in XYZ'}
```

I want to extract the generated SQL query, just in case if the user need to review it.
I can see the query in the intermediate steps, but Im not clear on how to fetch it.

Any help would be much appreciated!!
Thanks